# Why is reading a file using `array` successfully reads the file and terminates with an unknown error?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I am trying to read from a specific line/block using `array` manipulation of index, but the program is terminating with an unknown error after reading from the third line to end, and returning `255` , How to achieve it using the same method I implemented in the code if this is possible?

> Create a file with 10 blocks and name it `datafile.txt` then try to
> read the file starting from the third block using `index = 3` it will
> read from the the whole file starting from the 3rd line and then terminates with 255 telling file not accessible.
>
> The expected output is it should start reading from the third block to
> the end of the file `eof` and prints the output without any error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream datafile("datafile.txt");
    if(datafile)
    {
        cout << "The file is accessible to read" << '\n';
        const int DataCounterArray = 9;
        string nameList[DataCounterArray] = {""};
        string getDataTemporary = {""};
        int index = 3;
     while (!datafile.eof())
        {
            nameList[index] = getDataTemporary;
            index++;
            datafile >> getDataTemporary;
            cout << getDataTemporary << '\n';
        }
        for (int i=0; i < DataCounterArray; i++)
        {
            cout << nameList[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
    else{
    cout << "The file is not accessible to read" << '\n';
    return 255;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the exact contents of the input file is, what exactly?

Comment: Assuming the 255 return value is actually from your program's `return 255` part, common causes of file open failure are: (1) program's working directory not the same as the file; (2) file does not exist; (3) file is open for exclusive access in another application (_e.g._ your text editor); (4) user does not have correct permissions to read the file

Comment: Someone will come along mark this as a dupe with the proper sourcing, but one glaring issue is your while loop expression. Using `.eof()` can and often leads to off-by-one errors. You also have other issues with your code, like your main function having 2 return statements. I highly doubt that you're understanding your requirements correctly. You don't close the file when you're done. And your if check should be negated. It doesn't make a lot of sense to put the entire purpose of your program in a conditional.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Just a list of names/strings

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons?)

Comment: How many strings are in the file?  10, apparently?  You've created an array that only stores 9 elements.  And then you're _starting_ indexing that array at 3.  So you can only read in 6 values before your program hits undefined behavior.  Please attach a debugger and step through the program's execution to find the exact place where it terminates.

Comment: @paddy The file is accessible and it reads the whole file and prints the output as expected but then terminates with an unknown error and windows prompt a window that we are looking for the solution from Microsoft servers.

Comment: @sweenish The 255 should be only returned if the file is not accessible.

Comment: @paddy Yes 10 Strings

Comment: Yes, and if you attach a debugger, the program will probably break execution and show the call stack _before_ that exception window is shown and your process is terminated by the OS.  Now, read the rest of my comment about how your program has guaranteed undefined behavior.

Comment: What proof can you show that the file exists in the directory the program is executed from?

Comment: @paddy Yes, The file contains 10 elements/strings and I am trying to read only 7 strings starting from 3 to 10

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The program prints all the list of strings as expected and then return 255, its mean the file was accessible and now not accessible + windows exception of checking for the solution.

Comment: Your loop reads all strings in the file.  And possibly attempts another, due to improper use of the EOF test.  Your array holds only 9 values, and the 10th string will be stored at index 12.  Is there something you still don't understand?  I've kinda said it 3 times now, and you're still responding as if you haven't taken in what I'm saying.

Comment: @paddy Yes It reads all the strings from start to end but I am forcing it to read from the third string and it reads + at the same time it shows the file is not accessible returning 255

Comment: UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR

Comment: Look, try this: set `DataCounterArray` to a value of 20 and run your program.

Comment: @paddy Yes its now working fine, and I understand what the problem was )